# Extraer los datos de usuario desde la vista

Tags: php, laravel, ssl

No se si esto es posible, espero me ayuden.
Tengo un controlador `GeneralController` el cual tiene un metodo llamado `userData()`, este metodo lo que hace es de acuerdo al `user_id` de session que existe, devolverme los datos de usuario, pero no solo los de la tabla user, sino tambien de la tabla del tipo de usuario. Ejemplo

```
users && pacientes
users && Medico
users && Admin



$user_data = DB::table('users')
    ->join($table,$table.'.User_ID','users.id')
    ->select($table.'.*','users.id as user_id','users.role','users.email','users.estado')
    ->where('users.id','=',$id)
    ->first();
```

En fin, el punto es que me devuelve los datos de usuario. Ahora... lo que quiero hacer es estos datos, pasarlos a la vista porque necesito que en el `menu` se muestren, pero no me gustaria es tener que enviarlos por `compact` cada vez... hay alguna forma de poder acceder a ese metodo directo desde el `layout` general que estoy usando como plantilla? o que se precargue siempre. Porque como el menu se va a mostrar siempre, estos datos tambien tienen que mostrarse siempre.

Answer (score 0):

Quizás te sirva utilizar el método `share()` del facade `View`. Con eso puedes compartir una variable en todas tus vistas. Laravel recomienda usarlo en un Service Provider, puedes usar AppServiceProvider o crear el tuyo propio. [Aquí](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/views#sharing-data-with-all-views) está la documentación al respecto.